# Convert html entities into charactes problem

Tags: php, html

link

Im having trouble converting the html entites into html characters, (&# 8217;) i have tried using al the different php functions (html_entity_decode, htmlspecial characters etc...) None seem to be working, any ideas what function i need to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't that the characters are not decoded correctly, but that the browser is misinterpreting the decoded characters.

As the page is encoded using UTF-8, you need to specify that in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```